# How do I use awk to overwrite after the first two lines of the .csv file, without deleting them, and stop overwriting before the trailer?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am using this awk command:

```
 awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{gsub(/"/, "", $5); $5 = sprintf("%010s", $5);sub($5, "\"&\"");print}' Test_File > tmp && mv tmp Test_File
```

It removes double quotes around the 5th column, zero pads the column's data to 10, adds the quotes back in after zero padding the 5th column, and then overwrites the existing file.

However, this command does all of the above to the header and trailer as well,and I want to leave the header and trailer as they are, while just overwriting the body.

**Here is the initial Test_File data:**

```
Header 1, data, data, data, data, data
Header 2, data, data, data, data, data
column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6
1,2,3,4,"000005",6
1,2,3,4,"005", 6
Trailer
```

**Here is what my current awk command does to the Test_File data, it does not work:**

```
Header 1, data, data, data, "000000data", data
Header 2, data, data, data, "000000data", data
column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4, "00column 5", column 6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005",6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005",6
Trailer, data, data, data, "000000data", data
```

**Here is what I want after applying my awk script to the Test_File data:**

```
Header 1, data, data, data, data, data
Header 2, data, data, data, data, data
column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005",6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005",6
Trailer, data, data, data, data, data
```

Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you showed your efforts to us along with your problem(as we all are here to learn), keep it up.

Comment: you should define the rule of lines that skipping padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to pass the first 3 lines and last 1 line through unchanged, and do something to the rest of the lines, right? That's:

```
$ seq 7 | awk 'NR>1{print prev} {orig=$0} NR>3{$0="foo "$0} {prev=$0} END{print orig}'
1
2
3
foo 4
foo 5
foo 6
7
```

Just change `$0="foo "$0` to whatever it is you want to do with the lines between the first 3 and the last 1 and add whatever FS and OFS settings you use.

Comment: This works well thank you!But why did you pipe "Seq 7" into the awk command?

Answer (score 2):

I am considering that your 1st columns have strings `header` and `trailer` and you don't want to edit anything in them, so tweaked your code a bit, try following.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '$1!~/Header/ && $1!~/Trailer/ && $1!~/column/{gsub(/"/,"", $5); $5 = sprintf("%010s", $5);sub($5, "\"&\"");print;next} 1' Input_file  > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Header 1, data, data, data, data, data
Header 2, data, data, data, data, data
column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005",6
1,2,3,4,"0000000005", 6
Trailer, data, data, data, "000000data", data
```